# PHP LDAP add_user to Active Directory failing

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I get an "Object class violation" error when calling add_user.  I am connected and bound on port 636. I am doing an ldap_search on the samaccountname and this returns true if the account exists and false if it doesn't, so I'm pretty sure my connection is all correct.

The DN passed is:

```
CN=Test Student,CN=Users,DC=brewsternet,DC=org
```

and the attributes are:

```
Array
(
    [userprincipalname] => 888888888@brewsternet.org
    [samaccountname] => 888888888
    [userpassword] => {MD5}2m844Jh7R2MSYUkbBRuJCFRYUoM=
    [givenname] => Test
    [sn] => Student
    [cn] => Test Student
    [member] => CN=Test Student,CN=Users,DC=brewsternet,DC=org
)
```

I have searched for a solution for 3 days and I have run out of clues.  Any idea what to do?

A valid DN from an existing user is (I redacted the name):

```
CN=********,CN=Users,DC=brewsternet,DC=org
```

Comment: Does anyone have info on how to solve this?